# Pressed 'P' and something else now it crashed my blender

Tags: modeling

As described in the title, I wanted to separate a mesh with <kbd>P</kbd> but this happened instead. Now all I can do is close without saving and open from when I saved last time, which is hours ago.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to recover any auto saved file from your temp folder?

Comment: Also this question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender. These should be reported to the official [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/) instead.

Comment: It sounds like you went into game mode. To get out of it next time hit the Escape key.

Comment: If you want to separate things ensure that you are in edit mode 1st.